# How to use a List<interface> and LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq, methods

I have the following interface and classes and I get an error saying "Cannot implicitly convert World to IWord...".  Thank you for any help:

```
public interface IWord
{

}

public class Word : IWord
{

}

public class MyTest
{
    public IList<IWord> GetAll()
    {
        // I fixed, there is any better way?
        var list data.Where(x => x.Value == n).Select(o => new Word(o.Value, o.Key)).Cast<IWord>().ToList();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to change `List<Word>` to `List<IWord>`

Comment: Read up on [covariance and contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx). Essentially you cannot cast a `List<Word>` to an `IList<IWord>` because the latter could accept a `NewWord : IWord` but the former could not.

Comment: Well, my actually code uses a LINQ expression. Please see my update

Comment: remove `ToList()` from LINQ, then `return new List<IWord>(linq_result);`

Comment: @BenVoigt, it worked!